# Mapping from a specific point in Microsoft Graph API, Python

Tags: python, json, api, microsoft-graph-api

I've been beating my head against the wall for a couple of days now and can't quite come up with an answer.

Inside of the Microsoft Graph API, when you call for a specific type of email data it sends a JSON with a 'value' read at the top level.

```
    {
        "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('938381cd-71f5-4a3d-a381-0a59a721948a')/messages",
        "value": [
            {
                "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAD0YZL2mrEQQpwOvq9h/XWNAAACpJ2E\"",
                "bccRecipients": [],
                "body": {
```

I'm attempting to dump the JSON into a dict and go into the value key to be able to get to the data I actually need.

```
    print('\nGet user unread messages -> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=isRead ne true')
        user_MAIL = session.get(api_endpoint('me/messages?$filter=isRead ne true'))
     {len(user_MAIL.text)}\n')
        text = json.dumps(user_MAIL.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

The issue I keep running into is I can't figure out how to access the 'value' part. In Javascript I know I could just do something like a .map, but I've attempted several things here and can't seem to find an answer.

All I need to do is be able to enter the data from the value, and be able to list the keys and values of everything within 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found the answer.

If you do a for loop like this:

```
for key in range(length):
        print (json_object['value'][key]['id'])
        print (28* ' ', "BREAK")
```

You're able to access the top layer and grab exactly what you want, no matter how many loops you have.